# Webadministration module is not imported while running from C# application

Tags: c#, powershell

On my button click event, following  script is run. But when the services are executed, it does not display anything in the text file and the import module WebAdministration line shows the error message :

Cannot find a provider with the name 'WebAdministration'

Same script runs fine from powershell cmd

My script:

```
        $a = (Get-Service | Where {$_.DisplayName -Like "Microsoft Exchange*"} | % {$_.name + ' :' + $_.status}) -join "`n"


        write-output $a >> C:\temp.txt


            import-module WebAdministration
        $webapps = Get-WebSite Powershell
        $list = @()
        foreach ($webapp in get-childitem IIS:\AppPools\)
        {
                $name = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $webapp.name
                $item = @{}

                $item.WebAppName = $webapp.name
                $item.Version = (Get-ItemProperty $name managedRuntimeVersion).Value
                $item.State = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webapp.name).Value
                $item.UserIdentityType = $webapp.processModel.identityType
                $item.Username = $webapp.processModel.userName
                $item.Password = $webapp.processModel.password

                $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item
                $list += $obj
        }

        $abc = ($list | %{$_.Name+":"+ $_.ApplicatonPool+":"+$_.Protocol+":"+$_.PhysicalPath}) -join "`n"
        write-output "Details For Default WebApplication: `n $abc" >> C:\temp.txt
        cd iis:\
        $path ='Sites\Default Web Site\' + $website
        $abcd = (Get-WebConfiguration -Filter "System.WebServer/Security/Authentication/*" -PSPath $path | where {$_.enabled -eq $True} | % {$_.SectionPath + ' :' + $_.Location}) -join "`n" -replace "/system.webServer/security/authentication/",""
        write-output " Enable Authentication Mode For Given Websites:`n $abcd" >> C:\temp.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to run the Powershell script as administrator, there is no need to import the WebAdministration module

Answer (score 3):

Yep, run powershell/Exchange Management Console as Administrator by right clicking the icon -> 'run as administrator'.